# Vue.js Phone field not required, but not letting me submit if empty

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to be able to submit the following form without the phone field being required.
However, I would still like the phone field to be validated with regex before being able to be submit if a user inputs a phone number value.

So if blank, submit, ELSE check that it's valid before submitting. I thought had worked this out, but apparently not...

Any help is very much appreciated!

```js
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
          now: new Date().toISOString(),
          imgSrc:
            "",
          contact: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            address: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            zip: "",
            checked: false,
          },
          states: [
            {
              name: "Alabama",
              abr: "AL",
            },
            {
              name: "Alaska",
              abr: "AK",
            },
            {
              name: "American Samoa",
              abr: "AS",
            },
            {
              name: "Arizona",
              abr: "AZ",
            },
            {
              name: "Arkansas",
              abr: "AR",
            },
            {
              name: "California",
              abr: "CA",
            },
            {
              name: "Colorado",
              abr: "CO",
            },
            {
              name: "Connecticut",
              abr: "CT",
            },
            {
              name: "Delaware",
              abr: "DE",
            },
            {
              name: "District Of Columbia",
              abr: "DC",
            },
            {
              name: "Federated States Of Micronesia",
              abr: "FM",
            },
            {
              name: "Florida",
              abr: "FL",
            },
            {
              name: "Georgia",
              abr: "GA",
            },
            {
              name: "Guam",
              abr: "GU",
            },
            {
              name: "Hawaii",
              abr: "HI",
            },
            {
              name: "Idaho",
              abr: "ID",
            },
            {
              name: "Illinois",
              abr: "IL",
            },
            {
              name: "Indiana",
              abr: "IN",
            },
            {
              name: "Iowa",
              abr: "IA",
            },
            {
              name: "Kansas",
              abr: "KS",
            },
            {
              name: "Kentucky",
              abr: "KY",
            },
            {
              name: "Louisiana",
              abr: "LA",
            },
            {
              name: "Maine",
              abr: "ME",
            },
            {
              name: "Marshall Islands",
              abr: "MH",
            },
            {
              name: "Maryland",
              abr: "MD",
            },
            {
              name: "Massachusetts",
              abr: "MA",
            },
            {
              name: "Michigan",
              abr: "MI",
            },
            {
              name: "Minnesota",
              abr: "MN",
            },
            {
              name: "Mississippi",
              abr: "MS",
            },
            {
              name: "Missouri",
              abr: "MO",
            },
            {
              name: "Montana",
              abr: "MT",
            },
            {
              name: "Nebraska",
              abr: "NE",
            },
            {
              name: "Nevada",
              abr: "NV",
            },
            {
              name: "New Hampshire",
              abr: "NH",
            },
            {
              name: "New Jersey",
              abr: "NJ",
            },
            {
              name: "New Mexico",
              abr: "NM",
            },
            {
              name: "New York",
              abr: "NY",
            },
            {
              name: "North Carolina",
              abr: "NC",
            },
            {
              name: "North Dakota",
              abr: "ND",
            },
            {
              name: "Northern Mariana Islands",
              abr: "MP",
            },
            {
              name: "Ohio",
              abr: "OH",
            },
            {
              name: "Oklahoma",
              abr: "OK",
            },
            {
              name: "Oregon",
              abr: "OR",
            },
            {
              name: "Palau",
              abr: "PW",
            },
            {
              name: "Pennsylvania",
              abr: "PA",
            },
            {
              name: "Puerto Rico",
              abr: "PR",
            },
            {
              name: "Rhode Island",
              abr: "RI",
            },
            {
              name: "South Carolina",
              abr: "SC",
            },
            {
              name: "South Dakota",
              abr: "SD",
            },
            {
              name: "Tennessee",
              abr: "TN",
            },
            {
              name: "Texas",
              abr: "TX",
            },
            {
              name: "Utah",
              abr: "UT",
            },
            {
              name: "Vermont",
              abr: "VT",
            },
            {
              name: "Virgin Islands",
              abr: "VI",
            },
            {
              name: "Virginia",
              abr: "VA",
            },
            {
              name: "Washington",
              abr: "WA",
            },
            {
              name: "West Virginia",
              abr: "WV",
            },
            {
              name: "Wisconsin",
              abr: "WI",
            },
            {
              name: "Wyoming",
              abr: "WY",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        submitForm(e) {
          const isValid =
            this.contact.firstName &&
            this.contact.lastName &&
            this.contact.email &&
            this.validEmail(this.contact.email) &&
            this.validPhone(this.contact.phone) &&
            this.validZip(this.contact.zip);
          e.target.classList.add("was-validated");
          if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        },
        validEmail: function (email) {
          const re =
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
        },
        validPhone: function (phone) {
          const re = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
          return re.test(phone);
        },
        validZip: function (zip) {
          const re = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/;
          return re.test(zip);
        },
      },
    });

    app.mount("#awApp");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="vh-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />


    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- /Bootstrap 5 CSS-->

    <style>
      main > .container {
        padding: 60px 15px 0;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="awApp" class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
      <!-- FIXED NAVBAR AND/OR HEADER -->
      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img :src="imgSrc" alt="logo" width="120" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- / HEADER/NAVBAR -->

      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
      <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row my-5">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <img
                src="http://placehold.it/1200x400"
                alt="hero image"
                class="img-fluid"
              />
              <h2 class="mt-3">Headline goes here...</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Corporis dolore eaque, facere id molestias perspiciatis sit?
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>benefit 1</li>
                <li>benefit 2</li>
                <li>benefit 3</li>
              </ul>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad
                aliquid assumenda consectetur deleniti est ipsam nemo nobis
                officiis quasi, quod!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="card shadow p-3">
                <!--<img class="card-img-top rz-card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/400x100" alt="Card image cap">-->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Headline</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                  <form
                    novalidate
                    class="needs-validation"
                    name="mainForm"
                    @submit="submitForm"
                    method="post"
                  >
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstname" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >First Name*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="firstname"
                          type="text"
                          name="firstname"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.firstName"
                          id="awValid"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a first name.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastname" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Last Name*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="lastname"
                          type="text"
                          name="lastname"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.lastName"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a last name.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Email Address*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="email"
                          type="text"
                          name="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.email"
                          pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20})$"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid email.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="phone" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Phone
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="phone"
                          type="text"
                          name="phone"
                          class="form-control"
                          pattern="^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"
                          v-model="contact.phone"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid phone number.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="address1" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Street Address
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="address1"
                          type="text"
                          name="address1"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.address"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                        <label for="city" class="form-label mb-0">City</label>
                        <input
                          id="city"
                          type="text"
                          name="city"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.city"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                        <label for="state" class="form-label mb-0">State</label>
                        <select
                          id="state"
                          name="state"
                          v-model="contact.state"
                          class="form-select"
                        >
                          <option>##state##</option>
                          <option
                            v-for="state in states"
                            v-bind:value="state.abr"
                          >
                            {{state.name}}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="zip" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Zip Code</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="zip"
                          type="text"
                          name="zip"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.zip"
                          pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid zip code.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <input
                            id="checkbox1"
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="form-check-input"
                            name="check-me-out"
                            v-model="contact.checked"
                          />
                          <label for="checkbox1" class="form-check-label"
                            >Check me out</label
                          >
                          <div></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      class="btn btn-primary"
                      value="Submit"
                    />

                    <div>
                      <small class="form-text text-muted">
                        <em>* Denotes a required field.</em>
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->

      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="text-muted"
            >&copy; {{currentYear}} |
            <a href="##URL_PRIVACY##">Privacy Policy</a> |
            <a href="##URL_LEGAL##">Legal</a></span
          >
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- /FOOTER -->
    </div>

    <!--Bootstrap 5 JS-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!--/Bootstrap 5 JS-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a condition to the `isValid` Boolean that checks whether the phone field is empty:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    submitForm(e) {
      const isValid =
            this.contact.firstName &&
            this.contact.lastName &&
            this.contact.email &&
            this.validEmail(this.contact.email) &&
                     
            (!this.contact.phone || this.validPhone(this.contact.phone)) &&
            this.validZip(this.contact.zip);

      //...
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
          now: new Date().toISOString(),
          imgSrc:
            "",
          contact: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            address: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            zip: "",
            checked: false,
          },
          states: [
            {
              name: "Alabama",
              abr: "AL",
            },
            {
              name: "Alaska",
              abr: "AK",
            },
            {
              name: "American Samoa",
              abr: "AS",
            },
            {
              name: "Arizona",
              abr: "AZ",
            },
            {
              name: "Arkansas",
              abr: "AR",
            },
            {
              name: "California",
              abr: "CA",
            },
            {
              name: "Colorado",
              abr: "CO",
            },
            {
              name: "Connecticut",
              abr: "CT",
            },
            {
              name: "Delaware",
              abr: "DE",
            },
            {
              name: "District Of Columbia",
              abr: "DC",
            },
            {
              name: "Federated States Of Micronesia",
              abr: "FM",
            },
            {
              name: "Florida",
              abr: "FL",
            },
            {
              name: "Georgia",
              abr: "GA",
            },
            {
              name: "Guam",
              abr: "GU",
            },
            {
              name: "Hawaii",
              abr: "HI",
            },
            {
              name: "Idaho",
              abr: "ID",
            },
            {
              name: "Illinois",
              abr: "IL",
            },
            {
              name: "Indiana",
              abr: "IN",
            },
            {
              name: "Iowa",
              abr: "IA",
            },
            {
              name: "Kansas",
              abr: "KS",
            },
            {
              name: "Kentucky",
              abr: "KY",
            },
            {
              name: "Louisiana",
              abr: "LA",
            },
            {
              name: "Maine",
              abr: "ME",
            },
            {
              name: "Marshall Islands",
              abr: "MH",
            },
            {
              name: "Maryland",
              abr: "MD",
            },
            {
              name: "Massachusetts",
              abr: "MA",
            },
            {
              name: "Michigan",
              abr: "MI",
            },
            {
              name: "Minnesota",
              abr: "MN",
            },
            {
              name: "Mississippi",
              abr: "MS",
            },
            {
              name: "Missouri",
              abr: "MO",
            },
            {
              name: "Montana",
              abr: "MT",
            },
            {
              name: "Nebraska",
              abr: "NE",
            },
            {
              name: "Nevada",
              abr: "NV",
            },
            {
              name: "New Hampshire",
              abr: "NH",
            },
            {
              name: "New Jersey",
              abr: "NJ",
            },
            {
              name: "New Mexico",
              abr: "NM",
            },
            {
              name: "New York",
              abr: "NY",
            },
            {
              name: "North Carolina",
              abr: "NC",
            },
            {
              name: "North Dakota",
              abr: "ND",
            },
            {
              name: "Northern Mariana Islands",
              abr: "MP",
            },
            {
              name: "Ohio",
              abr: "OH",
            },
            {
              name: "Oklahoma",
              abr: "OK",
            },
            {
              name: "Oregon",
              abr: "OR",
            },
            {
              name: "Palau",
              abr: "PW",
            },
            {
              name: "Pennsylvania",
              abr: "PA",
            },
            {
              name: "Puerto Rico",
              abr: "PR",
            },
            {
              name: "Rhode Island",
              abr: "RI",
            },
            {
              name: "South Carolina",
              abr: "SC",
            },
            {
              name: "South Dakota",
              abr: "SD",
            },
            {
              name: "Tennessee",
              abr: "TN",
            },
            {
              name: "Texas",
              abr: "TX",
            },
            {
              name: "Utah",
              abr: "UT",
            },
            {
              name: "Vermont",
              abr: "VT",
            },
            {
              name: "Virgin Islands",
              abr: "VI",
            },
            {
              name: "Virginia",
              abr: "VA",
            },
            {
              name: "Washington",
              abr: "WA",
            },
            {
              name: "West Virginia",
              abr: "WV",
            },
            {
              name: "Wisconsin",
              abr: "WI",
            },
            {
              name: "Wyoming",
              abr: "WY",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        submitForm(e) {
          const isValid =
            this.contact.firstName &&
            this.contact.lastName &&
            this.contact.email &&
            this.validEmail(this.contact.email) &&
            (!this.contact.phone || this.validPhone(this.contact.phone)) &&
            this.validZip(this.contact.zip);
          e.target.classList.add("was-validated");
          if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        },
        validEmail: function (email) {
          const re =
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
          return re.test(email);
        },
        validPhone: function (phone) {
          const re = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
          return re.test(phone);
        },
        validZip: function (zip) {
          const re = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/;
          return re.test(zip);
        },
      },
    });

    app.mount("#awApp");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="vh-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />


    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- /Bootstrap 5 CSS-->

    <style>
      main > .container {
        padding: 60px 15px 0;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="awApp" class="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
      <!-- FIXED NAVBAR AND/OR HEADER -->
      <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img :src="imgSrc" alt="logo" width="120" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- / HEADER/NAVBAR -->

      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
      <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row my-5">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <img
                src="http://placehold.it/1200x400"
                alt="hero image"
                class="img-fluid"
              />
              <h2 class="mt-3">Headline goes here...</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Corporis dolore eaque, facere id molestias perspiciatis sit?
              </p>
              <ul>
                <li>benefit 1</li>
                <li>benefit 2</li>
                <li>benefit 3</li>
              </ul>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad
                aliquid assumenda consectetur deleniti est ipsam nemo nobis
                officiis quasi, quod!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <div class="card shadow p-3">
                <!--<img class="card-img-top rz-card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/400x100" alt="Card image cap">-->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Headline</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                  <form
                    novalidate
                    class="needs-validation"
                    name="mainForm"
                    @submit="submitForm"
                    method="post"
                  >
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="firstname" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >First Name*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="firstname"
                          type="text"
                          name="firstname"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.firstName"
                          id="awValid"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a first name.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label for="lastname" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Last Name*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="lastname"
                          type="text"
                          name="lastname"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.lastName"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a last name.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Email Address*</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="email"
                          type="text"
                          name="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.email"
                          pattern="^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20})$"
                          required
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid email.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="phone" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Phone
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="phone"
                          type="text"
                          name="phone"
                          class="form-control"
                          pattern="^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"
                          v-model="contact.phone"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid phone number.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <div class="col">
                        <label for="address1" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Street Address
                        </label>
                        <input
                          id="address1"
                          type="text"
                          name="address1"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.address"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                        <label for="city" class="form-label mb-0">City</label>
                        <input
                          id="city"
                          type="text"
                          name="city"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.city"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                        <label for="state" class="form-label mb-0">State</label>
                        <select
                          id="state"
                          name="state"
                          v-model="contact.state"
                          class="form-select"
                        >
                          <option>##state##</option>
                          <option
                            v-for="state in states"
                            v-bind:value="state.abr"
                          >
                            {{state.name}}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="zip" class="form-label mb-0"
                          >Zip Code</label
                        >
                        <input
                          id="zip"
                          type="text"
                          name="zip"
                          class="form-control"
                          v-model="contact.zip"
                          pattern="^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"
                        />
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid zip code.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-2">
                      <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <input
                            id="checkbox1"
                            type="checkbox"
                            class="form-check-input"
                            name="check-me-out"
                            v-model="contact.checked"
                          />
                          <label for="checkbox1" class="form-check-label"
                            >Check me out</label
                          >
                          <div></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      class="btn btn-primary"
                      value="Submit"
                    />

                    <div>
                      <small class="form-text text-muted">
                        <em>* Denotes a required field.</em>
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->

      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="text-muted"
            >&copy; {{currentYear}} |
            <a href="##URL_PRIVACY##">Privacy Policy</a> |
            <a href="##URL_LEGAL##">Legal</a></span
          >
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- /FOOTER -->
    </div>

    <!--Bootstrap 5 JS-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!--/Bootstrap 5 JS-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @tony19! I don't know why I was trying to overcomplicate this so much. Appreciate it!